# Does Exchange Multi-Mailbox Search Generate Logs?

Tags: exchange, full-text-search

Does Microsoft Exchange generate any logs when a [Multi-Mailbox Search](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335072(v=exchg.141).aspx) is performed, or otherwise create any type of audit record? I have a need to review the times, dates, and search terms for any past Multi-Mailbox Searches.

Additionally, is Multi-Mailbox Search *always* enabled on Exchange 2010+? Or is there any way to programmatically determine if it's enabled? Thanks!